# Shortcut to focus webpage in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I predominantly use a keyboard for navigating between windows and pages and scrolling. Sometimes I find that a webpage becomes "un-focussed" so I can't scroll with my keyboard and have to click on the window to focus it again and allow me to continue scrolling. I am not sure if this is a browser specific thing (I use Chrome) or an OS specific thing (I use Ubuntu). Is there a shortcut to refocus a webpage?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the <kbd>F6</kbd> key to switch between address bar, tab bar, and web page.

Comment: i didnt know you could do that.  good to know...  the question is whether I will remember it

Answer (score 1):

[Nunoxz](https://superuser.com/users/1698615/nunoxz) mentioned `F6`, but the direct shortcut is `Ctrl + F6`!

### EDIT

You can find it within the [Chrome Documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en#zippy=%2Cgoogle-chrome-feature-shortcuts)

[image]

Comment: You could improve your answer with a citation. How else can someone believe it without trying it.

Comment: Sorry, it turns out that I found it out by trial and error. I did try to find it through the documentation, but I couldn't. I only found the entry within the documentation after I discovered it by trial and error, but anyway I will update that. I would never guess the description would be `Skip to web contents`. I was escpecting for `page`, `view`, `focus`.

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows 10, so this may not work on a Linux System, but pressing `ALT + TAB` should make a window active again